# How to change the background colour of a collapsed navbar when it drops down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, styling

This is my first time using Stackoverflow so I hope I've done a good job explaining my problem:

I would like to change the background color of my navbar to white as it collapses down. i.e. when on a smaller screen, a button appears that allows you to press the action button in which shows you the content of the navbar. At the moment, my navbar background color is transparent and this theme follows after the navbar has been collapsed.

FYI - I am using bootstrap as you can see from my code below. The JS section is to add the solid class on to my navbar as you scroll down the page, however this is irrelevant to my collapsing problem.

I just can't seem to find the right class to edit in order to change the drop-down list background-color.

Here is my HTML (I apologise for the multiple lorem ipsum lines):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // Transition effect for navbar
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  // checks if window is scrolled more than 500px, adds/removes solid class
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
   $('.navbar').addClass('solid'),
    $('.navbar-brand').addClass('solid'),
    $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').addClass('solid');
  } else {
   $('.navbar').removeClass('solid'),
    $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('solid'),
    $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').removeClass('solid');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Oswald);

body {
 margin: 0;
}

body {
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0060, #ff6975);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0060 0, #ff6975 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #3c1fbd 0, #1100a8ad);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#FFFF0060", endColorstr="#FFFF6975", GradientType=0);
 font-family: Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.58;
 color: #555;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.white-text-container .fa-icon,
.white-text-container a,
.white-text-container h1,
.white-text-container h2,
.white-text-container h3,
.white-text-container h4,
.white-text-container h5,
.white-text-container p {
 color: #fff;
}

.section-container {
 padding: 60px 0 40px;
}


.navbar {
 height: 55px;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 z-index: 100;
 transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
 padding: 0rem 3rem !important;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
 color: rgb(253, 253, 253) !important;
}

.navbar.solid {
 background-color: white;
 transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
 box-shadow: 0 0 4px grey;
 color: black !important;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand.solid {
 color: black;
 transition: color 1s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.solid {
 color: black !important;
 transition: color 1s ease 0s;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 60px !important;
 margin-top: 25px !important;
 margin-bottom: 12.5px !important;
 font-family: Oswald, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
 font-weight: 400 !important;
 line-height: 1.1 !important;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin: .67em 0;
 display: block;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-block-start: 0.67em;
 margin-block-end: 0.67em;
 margin-inline-start: 0px;
 margin-inline-end: 0px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.fa-icon.fa-icon-2x {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-size: 28px;
}
.fa-icon {
 color: #000;
 width: 40px;
 height: 32px;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 29px;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/cv2.png">

</head>
<body>

    
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>   
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    
    <main class="content-wrapper">
  
        <header class="white-text-container section-container">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      
            </div>
        </header>



        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
             
                     <div class="card">
                       <div class="card-block">
                         <h2>About</h2>
                         <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-4">
                             <p><img src="./assets/images/img-01.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-8">
             
                           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                           <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                           <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                           <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                           <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                           <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                           <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
             
                           </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>

    </main>


    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the background color of my navbar drop-down list to be white when clicked on the open button.

Answer (score 0):

Plz try this code in css..

**css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
   #navbarMenu {
     background-color: #fff;
   }
   #navbarMenu a {
    color: #000 !important;
    padding: 7px 15px;
   }
.navbar-dark.solid .navbar-toggler span {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
.navbar-dark.solid .navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #000;
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, the background colour changed. However the button now disappears with the white background and no longer changed to black when scrolling down. Can you help please?

Comment: plz check my post.. i modified

Comment: You sir are my hero. Thank you very much and have a great rest of the day!

Comment: @Manikandan2811 You should explain it a bit, so everyone can understand what you are doing or what you're using.

Comment: Do u understand my ans?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 Yes, but you should explain explain the answer. For more information go to : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to control de screen width
and use [mix-blend-mode](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_mix-blend-mode.asp) for the button for simply change the colour depending on background colour. *(mix-blend-mode in **IE** not supported)*

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #navbarMenu {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  #navbarMenu a {
    color: #000 !important;
    padding: 7px 15px;
  }
  .navbar-dark.solid .navbar-toggler span {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  }
  .navbar-dark.solid .navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #000;
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Transition effect for navbar
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // checks if window is scrolled more than 500px, adds/removes solid class
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('solid'),
        $('.navbar-brand').addClass('solid'),
        $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').addClass('solid');
    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('solid'),
        $('.navbar-brand').removeClass('solid'),
        $('.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link').removeClass('solid');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Oswald);
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0060, #ff6975);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0060 0, #ff6975 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #3c1fbd 0, #1100a8ad);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#FFFF0060", endColorstr="#FFFF6975", GradientType=0);
  font-family: Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.58;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.white-text-container .fa-icon,
.white-text-container a,
.white-text-container h1,
.white-text-container h2,
.white-text-container h3,
.white-text-container h4,
.white-text-container h5,
.white-text-container p {
  color: #fff;
}

.section-container {
  padding: 60px 0 40px;
}

.navbar {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
  padding: 0rem 3rem !important;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgb(253, 253, 253) !important;
}

.navbar.solid {
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px grey;
  color: black !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand.solid {
  color: black;
  transition: color 1s ease 0s;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.solid {
  color: black !important;
  transition: color 1s ease 0s;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px !important;
  margin-top: 25px !important;
  margin-bottom: 12.5px !important;
  font-family: Oswald, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  line-height: 1.1 !important;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: .67em 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-block-start: 0.67em;
  margin-block-end: 0.67em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fa-icon.fa-icon-2x {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.fa-icon {
  color: #000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #navbarMenu {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  #navbarMenu a {
    color: #000 !important;
    padding: 7px 15px;
  }
  .navbar-dark.solid .navbar-toggler span {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  }
  .navbar-dark.solid .navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #000;
  }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/cv2.png">

</head>

<body>


  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <main class="content-wrapper">

    <header class="white-text-container section-container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

      </div>
    </header>



    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h2>About</h2>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <p><img src="./assets/images/img-01.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">

                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                  <p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

  </main>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @SamR Remember to "check" the answer that solves your problem.